# Radio not disabling due to loop

Tags: javascript, php, radio-button

This is my radio disabling function.

```
<script>
function disableElement()
{
var dis = '<?php echo $dis_value; ?>';
document.getElementById(dis).disabled=true;
}
</script>
```

And I will call it when the page is loaded!

```
<body onLoad="disableElement()">
```

And the radio button is displayed through loop..!

```
echo '<form method="post" action="trainingserver.php">';
$i = 1;
while($i <= $num_rows)
{
echo '<input type="radio" id="dis"'.$i.'"" name="select" value="'.$i.'" />';
echo  $poke[$i]."<br>";
echo 'Level:'.$level[$i]."<br>";
echo 'Health:'.$health[$i]."<br>";
$i++;
}
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select Pokemon!" />';
echo '</form>';
```

So the radio ids would be like: dis1,dis2 ... dis6

But its not disabling it...! I think its because of the while loop, I used..! what should I do..?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? `console.log()` is your friend.

Comment: Sorry, never used it..can i tell me how should I do it?

Comment: In Chrome press F12 and click console. In your JS `console.log(something);` where something is an array, a string, an object, etc. Firefox has Firebug extension.

Comment: Can you show the outputted HTML, not the PHP that generates it?

Comment: I wonder why you aren't using a for loop, but regardless your code looks solid. Try posting dis_value for us to see since it seems that is the only thing that could be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
echo '<input type="radio" id="dis"'.$i.'"" name="select" value="'.$i.'" />';
```

should be (note the removed quotes from **id**):

```
echo '<input type="radio" id="dis'.$i.'" name="select" value="'.$i.'" />';
```